# How to perform a while loop, keep formula in cell and apply into entire row? Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a Macros using Excel and Visual Basic where I can perform an addition between a cell and another cell that has a formula in it. I need to perform this addition until the cell with the formula reaches 0.

Let's say, if:

C2 = 10,000
H2 (the one with the formula) = -40,000

I have to add the 40,000 from H2 to C2, so I can get 50,000 and H2 reaches 0. H2 would reach 0 due to its formula.

What I have tried to accomplish this is by using a While Loop. However, this loop gets stuck in infinite and also my H2 cell loses it's formula.

This is my code:

```
Dim n1 As Double
Dim n2 As Double

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)            
    n1 = Cells(2, 8).Value
    n2 = Cells(2, 3).Value

    Do While n1 <> 0
        n2 = n2 + (n1 * -1)
        Cells(2, 3).Value = n2
        n1 = Cells(2, 8).Value       
    Loop
End Sub
```

Also, I need to apply this very same method but on every row of C and H where they have a value.

Comment: You're not doing anything with n2. And you're assigning n1, which comes from H2, back to H2, overwriting any formula that lives in H2. That code does nothing useful. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to add C2 with H2 till H2 reaches 0 and also that this can be applied to the entire row of C2 and H2 where there are values.

Comment: What is the formula in H2? I'm still not seeing what the bigger picture is and why you want to use VBA to set H2 to 0. What is the purpose of all this?

Comment: you have a problem with basic math. if you add -40000 to 10000 you will get -30000

Comment: H2 interacts with other cells to calculate a value. When C2 changes, so does H2.

Comment: Here it how it works:

B2 = 100,000 | C2 = 10,000 | D2 = C2 + B2 | E2 = 50,000 | F2 = D2 -E2 | G2 = 100,000 | H2 = F2 -G2

Comment: H2 .... what is the formula?

Comment: @Midori_hige, so you want to run this for entire C and H column up to the last range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
Dim n1 As Double
Dim n2 As Double

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lastrow, i As Variant
    lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        n1 = Cells(i, 8).Value
        n2 = Cells(i, 3).Value
        Do While n1 <> 0
            n2 = n2 + (n1 * -1)
            Cells(i, 3).Value = n2
            n1 = Cells(i, 8).Value
        Loop
    Next i
End Sub
```